# Passing variable arguments to function

Tags: javascript, variables, coffeescript, argument-passing

I've set a function with variable arguments:

```
myfunc: (cmd, args...)->
    # cmd is a string
    # args is an array
```

And can be called like:

```
myfunc("one") # cmd = "one", args = undefined
myfunc("one","two") # cmd = "one", args = ["two"]
# etc...
```

Now, what if I want to call it with unknown number of arguments?
Let's say I want to pass an array of args instead of `arg1, arg2, arg3,..` how is that possible?

Trying `myfunc("one",["two","three"])` or `myfunc("one",someArgs)` leads to the unfortunate:

```
# cmd = "one"
# args = [ ["two","three"] ];
```

Ideas?

---

**P.S.** I made it this to work by adding these ultra-simple lines in my function. But is there no other way?

```
if args? and args[0] instanceof Array
    args = args[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually use `Function.prototype.apply` for this. Splats can be used in an argument to list to build an array or in a function call to expand an array; from [the fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

> **Splats...**
>
> [...] CoffeeScript provides splats `...`, both for function definition as well as invocation, making variable numbers of arguments a little bit more palatable.
>
> ```
> awardMedals = (first, second, others...) ->
>   #...
>
> contenders = [
>   #...
> ]
>
> awardMedals contenders...
> ```

So you can say things like this:

```
f('one')

f('one', 'two')

f('one', ['two', 'three']...)
# same as f('one', 'two', 'three')

args = ['where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house?']
f(args...)
# same as f('where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house?')
```

and The Right Thing will happen.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ztesehsj/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
myfunc.apply @, [ "one", "two", "three" ]
```

[Demo on CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:myfunc%20%3D%20(cmd%2C%20args...)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20cmd%20%2B%20%22%3A%20%22%20%2B%20args.join%20'%2C%20'%0A%0Amyfunc.apply%20%40%2C%20%5B%20%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%20%5D)